# Complex MapReduce Query with RavenDB

Tags: mapreduce, ravendb

Hope you can help me !!

I am collecting tweets, which have a created_at date (DataPublicacao), and some Hashtags. Each tweet refers to a broadcaster (redeId), and a show (programaId).
I want to query the database for the 20 most used hashtags in a certain period.

I have to map each hashtag, when it was used, and to which broadcaster and tv show it refers to.

Then, I need to be able to count the occurrences of each hashtag in a certain period (I dont know how).

```
public class Tweet : IModelo
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string RedeId { get; set; }
    public string ProgramaId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataPublicacao { get; set; }
    public string Conteudo { get; set; }
    public string Aplicacao { get; set; }
    public Autor Autor { get; set; }
    public Twitter.Monitor.Dominio.Modelo.TweetJson.Geo LocalizacaoGeo { get; set; }
    public Twitter.Monitor.Dominio.Modelo.TweetJson.Place Localizacao { get; set; }
    public Twitter.Monitor.Dominio.Modelo.TweetJson.Entities Entidades { get; set; }
    public string Imagem { get; set; }
    public Autor Para_Usuario { get; set; }
    public string Retweet_Para_Status_Id { get; set; }
}
```

And the "entities" are hashtags, usermentions, and urls.

I tried to group the hashtags by broadcaster, tv show, and text, and listing the dates of the occurrences. Then, I have to transform the results, so I can count the occurrences on that period.

```
    public class EntityResult
    {
        public string hashtagText { get; set; }
        public string progId { get; set; }
        public string redeId { get; set; }
        public int listCount { get; set; }
    }

    public class HashtagsIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Tweet, HashtagsIndex.ReduceResults>
    {
        public class ReduceResults
        {
            public string hashtagText { get; set; }
            public DateTime createdAt { get; set; }
            public string progId { get; set; }
            public string redeId { get; set; }
            public List<DateTime> datesList { get; set; }
        }

        public HashtagsIndex()
        {
            Map = tweets => from tweet in tweets
                            from hts in tweet.Entidades.hashtags
                            where tweet.Entidades != null
                            select new
                            {
                                createdAt = tweet.DataPublicacao,
                                progId = tweet.ProgramaId,
                                redeId = tweet.RedeId,
                                hashtagText = hts.text,
                                datesList = new List<DateTime>(new DateTime[] { tweet.DataPublicacao })
                            };

            Reduce = results => from result in results
                                group result by new { result.progId, result.redeId, result.hashtagText }
                                    into g
                                    select new
                                    {
                                        createdAt = DateTime.MinValue,
                                        progId = g.Key.progId,
                                        redeId = g.Key.redeId,
                                        hashtagText = g.Key.hashtagText,
                                        datesList = g.ToList().Select(t => t.createdAt).ToList()
                                    };
        }
    }
```

And the query I made so far is:

```
                    var hashtags2 = session.Query<dynamic, HashtagsIndex>().Customize(t => t.TransformResults((query, results) =>
                        results.Cast<dynamic>().Select(g =>
                        {
                            Expression<Func<DateTime, bool>> exp = o => o >= dtInit && o <= dtEnd;

                            int count = g.Where(exp);
                            return new EntityResult
                            {
                                redeId = g.redeId,
                                progId = g.progId,
                                hashtagText = g.hashtagText,
                                listCount = count
                            };
                        }))).Take(20).ToList();
```

Now I need to OrderByDescending(t=>t.count), so I cant Take(20) most used hashtags on that period.

How do I do that?

Comment: Please post some code to show what you are asking about.  Your question doesn't make much sense as it is currently written.

Comment: Hi Matt. Is it any clearer? If not, please, tell me, and I will edit my question.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to filter items before the mapreduce process?

A map/reduce index is just like any other index.  All documents are processed through all indexes, always.  So when phrased with "before" like you asked, the answer is clearly "no".

But I think you are just interested in filtering items *during* the indexing, and that is easily done in the map:

```
Map = items => from item in items
               where item.foo == whatever  // this is how you filter
               select new
               {
                 // whatever you want to map
               }
```

This index will process all documents, but the resulting index will only contain items that match the filter you specified in the where clause.

> Is it possible to subsequently group by features, like users by age, and then by region

Grouping is done in the reduce step.  That is what map/reduce is all about.

My advice to you (and I mean no disrespect by this), is to walk before you try to run.  Build a simple prototype or set of unit tests, and try first just basic storage and retrieval.  Then try basic indexing and querying.  Then try a *simple* map reduce, such as counting all your tweets.  Only then should you attempt an advance map/reduce with other groupings.  And if you run into trouble, then you will have code you can post here for help.

> Is it possible?

Of course.  Anything is possible. :)

Comment: Maybe I didn't make myself clear. My English is not that good =/. I have a condition, which is not previously known. I must filter by date (where item.created_at < DateTime.Now, for example). I do have experience on MapReduce, and yes, that offended me a bit.
An user will access my website, and choose a period, a program or broadcaster, and this user wants to know the most used hashtags, or urls. How can I do this with MapReduce?

Comment: That isn't a case for map/reduce.  You would create an index for your `created_at` field.  You can specify a where clause to filter the data from this index during a *query*.  You can read about this [here](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/client-api/querying/using-linq-to-query-ravendb).

Comment: Just to clarify - aggregating the counts of tweets grouping by hashtag, url, etc, *is* a map/reduce index.  In order to filter by a `DateTime`, you are going to have to decide on reasonable intervals to bucket the data into - that's part of your index as well.  But filtering that index by a parameter such as `DateTime.UtcNow` is what is done at time of query.

Comment: And I should group by hashtags, urls, and userMentions in the client machine?? It would be very expensive... I would have to bring more then 200k tweets. There must be a better way.

Comment: No, the grouping is done in the map/reduce index on the server.  Only the filter where you provide variable information (such as DateTime.Now) is done at query time.

Comment: Here, [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mj1856/5699993) should help illustrate.  And very sorry if I offended you.

Comment: Now that I see your gist, it makes sense. I will try, and I will get back to you. Thank you for the gist. Thank you for helping me with this.

Comment: your gist helped me, but I still need help. Could you please take a look on this edited question? I tried many ways, but I may be missing something.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't make sense of what you are asking or trying to do now.  Can you please edit and clean up the question, and be very clear about the current state of things and what you are wanting?  Why did you introduce `dynamic`? What are you actually trying to acomplish?  Your `Reduce` doesn't actually reduce anything, and I've got no idea why you are trying to build a list of dates.

Comment: Also, we're starting to reach the limits of what StackOverflow is designed for.  Someone will probably close this as "too localized", and they would be correct.  If you can't make the question more general, you should probably ask for help on the [RavenDB Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/ravendb) instead.